# Htaccess Need: http to https - nonexisting files, folders, subdomains to 404 - Only first is working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to add rewrites in .htaccess as described in title, but only the first one works, here is how my .htaccess looks now:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /404.php [R,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

**Examples that does not work**

These two NON EXISTING SUBDOMAINS examples just hang then show "Unable to connect", but I want them to show REAL 404 error page:

```
http://nonexisting.example.com
https://nonexisting.example.com
```

If we enter NON EXISTING FILES or FOLDERS, for example:

```
https://example.com/nonexistingfile.php
https://example.com/nonexistingfolder/
```

it shows my 404.php page allright BUT they turn up as a SOFT 404 and I want it to show the REAL 404 error page.

I have tried around 30 different variations of the second Rewrite section without any success. Some code returned a REAL 404 code but showed a messed up page not my 404.php page.

Comment: What do you mean by `SOFT 404`?

Comment: The "non existing subdomains" are working correctly unless you have a wildcard DNS record.

Comment: @anubhava Accorind to google : The target URL doesn't exist, but your server is not returning a 404 (file not found) error

Comment: @Tigger The DNS is set to: 

    **Type | Host | Value**
    A Record | @ | IP-ADDRESS
    URL Redirect Record | www | h t t p s : / / example.com

Comment: So you need a wildcard DNS entry: `*.yourdomain.com`

Comment: For the real 404, send the correct  header in 404.php: `header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found')` before any output is sent, e.g. at the very top of the file.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a rewrite rule here which is just redirecting all non-existing files or directories to `/404.php` with `R=302`.

Just try this code:

```
# will send correct 404 status as well
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,NE,L]
```

Comment: it seems to work like another one I tried which was that it is showing REAL 404 code but the page (404.php) seems messed up with style, html etc. any idea?

Comment: I have added full links to each css, js, images respectively without no effect. I use no other rewrites that your example.

Comment: how does your 404 php header look like except for header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]." 404 Not Found"); OR header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found"); ?

Comment: My `404.php` doesn't have any `header` function. Just regular HTML data with custom message and usual css/js/images links

Comment: You know what, I made a completely new 404.php without any PHP header and now ALL seems to work excellent!